# MySQL Stored Procedure Updating Status of Accounts Error Code: 1329

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-code

I have a situation in which I would like to iterate through a "schedPayments" table that stores a schedule of payments corresponding with a client in the "client" table.  The client table also contains a "status" column at the moment holds a 0 for "Past Due" and a 1 for "Current".  When the balance from the client table is greater than the supposed balance from the schedPayments table AND today's date is later than the date the payment was scheduled for, the status column in the clients table should be set to 0.

I may be completely off the wall with my solution, but I keep getting Error Code: 1329.  No Data - zero rows fetched, selected or processed.  The MySQL Workbench lacks some major debugging capabilities that I wish it had.  The documentation also doesn't quite cover what I need either in this situation.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `project`.`status_update` ()
BEGIN  
DECLARE balance DECIMAL(20) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cID INT(10) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE currentID INT(10) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE supposedBal DECIMAL(20) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE payDate DATE;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ClientID,SupposedBalance,Date FROM project.schedpayments;

OPEN cur1;

status_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO cID, supposedBal, payDate;
    BLOCK2: BEGIN 
        DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT balance FROM project.client WHERE ID=cID;
        OPEN cur2;  
        FETCH cur2 INTO balance;
        IF currentID > cID THEN
            SET currentID = cID;
            IF (CURDATE() > payDate) AND (supposedBal < balance) THEN
                UPDATE feeagree SET Status=0 WHERE ID=cID;
            END IF;
            CLOSE Cur2;

        END IF;
    END BLOCK2;

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END $$
```

You can see the remnants of how I had enclosed the entire procedure in a block and that only resulted in the compiler thinking the first block ended with END BLOCK2; and that resulted in an Error Code 1325. Cursor is already open.

I am definitely making this more complicated than necessary, so any help would be much appreciated.  The only way I learn this stuff is trial by fire, and it is super hot today.

Comment: Can you post some sample data for both tables and desired outcome relevant to that sample data? I believe you don't need a cursor for this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't need all those cursors and you can achieve your goal with one `UPDATE` statement.

It's hard to be precise without seeing your tables structures and sample data, but a more succinct version of your SP might look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE status_update()
  UPDATE feeagree 
     SET Status = 0 
   WHERE ID IN
  (
     SELECT p.cID
       FROM schedpayments p JOIN client c
         ON p.cID = p.ID
      WHERE p.Date < CURDATE() 
        AND p.SupposedBalance < c.balance
      GROUP BY p.cID
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...

DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = true;
OPEN cur1;

status_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO cID, supposedBal, payDate;
    IF DONE = true THEN LEAVE status_loop; END IF;

...

SET DONE = false;
END LOOP;
```

The SET DONE = false at the end resets DONE in case anything in the inner block results in it getting set to TRUE;